# UICollectionview userinteraction disable of a first cell ,disables few other cells also on scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Hi I want to disable the first cell of uicollectionview when in editing mode.I did the following code in cellforrow

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


   MainCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.curveimageView.image = nil;

   if(indexPath.item == 0){    
    [cell.curveimageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"AddCell"]];
     cell.subTitleText.text = @"New Cell";

       if(isEditing){
           [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
           [cell setAlpha:0.5];
       }
       else{
           [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
           [cell setAlpha:1];
       }
   }
   else{

        [cell.curveimageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FlowerImage"]];
        cell.subTitleText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld%@",(long)indexPath.row,@"Hello is this looking ok"];
   }

   [cell setTag:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

At first time in editing mode ,I am able to get the user click on all cells but after scrolling ,few cells in first row is disabled in random manner.Could anyone suggest me a solution to solve this issue.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is: your first cell is reuse after scrolling, and your code doesn't change its state, quickly you can solve with this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


  MainCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.curveimageView.image = nil;

if(indexPath.item == 0){    
[cell.curveimageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"AddCell"]];
 cell.subTitleText.text = @"New Cell";

   if(isEditing){
       [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
       [cell setAlpha:0.5];
   }
   else{
       [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
       [cell setAlpha:1];
   }
}
 else{

    [cell.curveimageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FlowerImage"]];
    cell.subTitleText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld%@",(long)indexPath.row,@"Hello is this looking ok"];
// Add this:
[cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
       [cell setAlpha:1];
 }

 [cell setTag:indexPath.row];
  return cell;
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

When you do  `[cell setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];` on a cell, the cells that will be created using that will be affected too. Because they are on a queue that you can reuse. So, you need to enable user interaction in else of item 0 control:

```
if (indexPath.item == 0){
...
} else {
   [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Issue is reusing the cell . set the `setUserInteractionEnabled` in else case ...

```
else{

//  set user intraction enable .
[cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

[cell.curveimageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FlowerImage"]];
cell.subTitleText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld%@",(long)indexPath.row,@"Hello is this looking ok"];

   [cell setAlpha:1];
 }
```

hope it  help you .

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 5 I solved this issue by implementing delegate function of CollectionView

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
- get your cell where you want to disable user interaction
- if cell meet condition you want - return false
- else return true
}
```

Hope this helps.